# get dropdown item count using selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
IWebElement from = m_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("mydropdownxpath"));
from.Click(); // to open dropdown
```

My dropdown type is input dropdown and I haven't used SelectElement or IList in my code. How can i get dropdown item count with below as my source code?

```
<select class="classname" name="ddldropdown" required>

<option data-fas="themered" value="" disabled selected>state</option>

<optgroup label="area">
   <option data-fas="maptheme" value="state1"> state 1 </option>
   <option data-fas="maptheme" value="state2"> state 2 </option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="Airport">
   <option data-fas="maptheme" value="ABC"> ABC </option>
   <option data-fas="maptheme" value="XYZ"> XYZ </option>
</optgroup>                       

</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your dropdown is `<select>`, not `<input>`. `SelectElement` is the correct way to handle it

```
IWebElement from = m_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("mydropdownxpath"));
SelectElement select = SelectElement(form);
int count = select.Options.Count; // 5
```

Comment: SelectElement statement showed - "'Element should have been select but was input'"? Any idea?

Comment: @StavanShah It means the element was indeed `<input>`, but the html you posted doesn't have `<input>` tag anywhere, it has `<select>` tag.

Comment: the dropdown comes from the mdb purchased theme (https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/select/)

Comment: @StavanShah This is still `<select>`. Check if the locator it correct.

Comment: Guy - do i need to check the Xpath is correct or not? as I am locating my dropdown using relative/absolute xpath

Comment: thanks for the help it worked!! found the correct xpath.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, I had to change the second line to

```
SelectElement select = new SelectElement(form);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).